# Getting Current Date and Time of SQL Server

Tags: android, sql-server

i'm kinda new to this, but i have been doing some research about how i could retrieve the current date and time of an ms sql server(not to be confused with retrieving a datetime column) and display on a textview, the main reason why i'm trying to achieve this is to display the current date and time of the server and avoid confusion due to changing of date and time settings on the android device itself.

i have been looking at different posts here in stackoverflow but none of those seem to produce the result i'm looking for, if incase i overlooked the proper post that has the answer that i need, please do tell me so i can mark as solved :) thanks

i really just want to know if this is a dead end and not possible or there is some kind of code or third party library that allows this... thank in advance, all feedback is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GETDATE()` OR `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` will gives you the current date & time in the SQL Server

Comment: can you show me a sample code on how it would work and be displayed on a textview? please take note... i'm not retrieving a FIELD,

Comment: @AlphaGabrielV.Timbol `Select Getdate()` will return you the current date and time of server

Comment: thanks i will try that, will mark as answer once it works, i never thought an SQL query would work without any tables or any columns required. will try in a sec

Comment: how do i make it show the time as well? i tried CURRENT_TIMESTAMP but it only shows date

Comment: ohh NVM, i just change my ResultSet.getDate() into ResultSet.getTimestamp, thanks so much for the help